# Property or indexer '' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class that is a list of class objects.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserRequestOrders
{
    private List<RTORequestOrder> m_thisUsersOrders = new List<RTORequestOrder>();

    public List<RTORequestOrder> RequestOrders
    {
        get { return m_thisUsersOrders; }
        set { m_thisUsersOrders = value; }
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of this object I need to populate the list variable When m_thisUsersOrders with an existing list of requests (from a viewstate).

```
MyOrders.RequestOrders = (List<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder>)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];
```

When the page posts back, I cast the viewstate into a list of RTORequestOrder objects, and try to set the RequestOrders property, I get the message that the property or indexer cannot be assigned to.  I have a "SET" accessor for the property.

All posts that I have read on this topic state that I need to modify scope in the application settings, but I am not sure how that applies here.  I don't have any application settings set.

I am hoping someone can help me understand how I can populate the list from an existing list.

EDIT: Nico, Thanks for your response!  Below is the full code from the code behind page.  "MyOrders" and "lst" are essentially the same thing. When I am working with "lst" everything works the way that I want it to.  The reason that I want to use the "MyOrders" object instead is because I have a method that returns the list as a datatable with only the fields I need to display. (I didnt' show that code because the issue appears to be with the "SET" accessor.) "lst" has the same signiture as the "MyOrders.RequestOrders".  Why can I cast the the viewstate into the lst object, but not the MyOrders object?

EDIT: Grant, thanks for your response as well.  I don't know how to set breakpoints for ASP pages...  :(

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
RTODataEntryObjects.UserRequestOrders MyOrders = new RTODataEntryObjects.UserRequestOrders();
List<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder> lst = new List<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder>();


void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["vsMyOrders"] == null)
    {
        NewDataGrid.DataSource = (RTODataEntryObjects.UserRequestOrders)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];  // code to show the data in the grid when page loading
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    NewDataGrid.EnableViewState = true;
    NewDataGrid.DataSource = (RTODataEntryObjects.UserRequestOrders)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];
    NewDataGrid.DataBind();

}

public void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int id = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text); // dynamically getting the data from the frontend.
    string name = TextBox2.Text; // dynamically getting the data from the frontend.
    if (ViewState["vsMyOrders"] != null) // if the view state is already having data then can update the list and assign again to the viewstate later.
    {
        lst = (List<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder>)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];
        MyOrders.RequestOrders = (List<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder>)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];
    }
    RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder thisOrder = new RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder(id, name, User.Identity.Name, System.Environment.MachineName);

    lst.Add(thisOrder); // 
    MyOrders.AddNew(thisOrder);

    ViewState["vsMyOrders"] = MyOrders;
    NewDataGrid.DataSource = (IList<RTODataEntryObjects.RTORequestOrder>)ViewState["vsMyOrders"];
    NewDataGrid.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles just fine. Are there other build errors that need to be addressed?

Comment: Also can you show us the "MyOrders" field \ property. Is it readonly? Missing the setter?